# How to Boot FreeDOS on Newer Intel CPUs?

Tags: boot, bios, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media, freedos

I have 2 PCs at home:
A Desktop PC (i3-3220),
and a Mini-PC I bought recently, that has a Celeron J3355 CPU (7th generation - "Apollo Lake") in it.

I am using Windows on my Desktop PC,
and occasionaly also booting to FreeDOS, using a Bootable USB Flash Drive that I created with Rufus.

FreeDOS boots with no problem on the Desktop PC,
but when I took that USB Flash Drive and connected it to the Mini-PC,
all attempts to boot from it have not succeeded yet.

At first I thought maybe it's some BIOS setting regarding USB that needs to be fixed,
but after going over the BIOS, I think that all relevant settings are OK.
(other Bootable USB Flash Drives that I tried on that Mini-PC, boot very well)

I also tried another USB Flash Drive that has MS-DOS on it,
and it too, simply does not boot on the Mini-PC.

These 2 are the only 2 Bootable USB Flash Drives that did not boot on that Mini-PC,
all other USB Flash Drives that I have boot without any problem.

So this leads me to wonder:
Do newer Intel CPUs have a problem with DOS/FreeDOS?
Is there any way I can succeed booting that USB Flash Drive with FreeDOS?

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to boot FreeDOS?

Comment: Either it writes nothing (black screen for half a second) and then immediately returns to the Boot Options menu, or, it gives a message "Please insert a Bootable Media and press any key".. (and that's after I load the boot menu with F7, and choose the USB Flash Drive which appears correctly as an option in that menu)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say which Intel Mini-PC you have exactly so I may be off-target but as far as I remember all off them come with BIOS configured by default for UEFI boot and DOS (and I suppose this also applies to FreeDOS) doesn't support that as it predates UEFI era.

If you are lucky your Mini-PC may have CSM module and may support so called "legacy boot" but I have a strong feeling that they don't.

Comment: Thank you Tomek. The Mini-PC is called Beelink BT3-X. Its BIOS is actually completely open - you can set everything. I did play with the UEFI/Legacy settings, and I also tried changing "OS Type" from "Windows" to "MS-DOS". Nothing helped, tested on USB Flash Drives with MS-DOS and with FreeDOS..